# How I can center two TextViews, when one TextView can be GONE?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am using two `TextView`s to show contact name and company name, one below another with the use of DataBinding technique. Company name is optional field, so it can disappear.

**1.** I have been using such method in **item_contact.xml** :

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
    <variable
        name="info"
        type="com.myproject.objects.InfoObject"/>
</data>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="70dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_contact_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text='@{info.getAccountName() == null ? info.getName() : String.format(@string/item_meeting_time_period, info.getName(), info.getAccountName() )}'
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        />

    <include layout="@layout/bottom_line_divider" />

</RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

**strings.xml**:

```
<string name="item_meeting_time_period" translatable="false">%1$s\n%2$s</string>
```

So the strings were just one below another. But now I need to change the `textSize` and `textColor` of the second row. In this case I need to use two TextViews and the current solution I am using is to center in  `LinearLayout`.

**2.** Second solution with two TextViews.

my **item_contact.xml** :

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
    <variable
        name="info"
        type="com.myproject.objects.InfoObject"/>
</data>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="70dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_contact_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:text="@{info.getName()}"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_contact_accountName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="@{info.getAccountName()}"
    android:textColor="@color/gray"
    android:textSize="12sp"            
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle"
    android:visibility="@{info.getAccountName().isEmpty() ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    />

</LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/bottom_line_divider" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But in this case if the second `TextView` is `Gone` than the first TextView still will render on the top of the `LinearLayout` as it suppose that the second view can be `Visible`.

**QUESTION:** What is the solution to make first TextView be centralized vertically if the second TextView invisible and both of them be centralized if the second TextView visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, summing up. Finally I have finished everything and it is working as I wanted, so if there is only one `TextView` visible than it is centralized verticaticaly, or if there are both `TextView`s visible, both of them are centered.

**item_contact.xml** :

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
    <variable
        name="info"
        type="fi.lunni.mobileadvisor.ui.objects.InfoObject"/>
    <variable
        name="handler"
        type="fi.lunni.mobileadvisor.ui.adapters.ContactsAdapter"/>
</data>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="70dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_contact_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:text="@{info.getName()}"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_gravity="@{info.getAccountName().length() > 0 }"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_contact_accountName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@{info.getAccountName()}"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle"
            android:visibility="@{info.getAccountName().length() > 0 ?  View.VISIBLE : View.GONE }"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/bottom_line_divider" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And a function in a separate class **BindingAdapters.java** :

```
@BindingAdapter("android:layout_gravity")
public static void setLayoutGravity(TextView view, boolean belowViewExists){
    if(view.getId() == R.id.item_contact_name){
        Log.d(TAG, "setLayoutVertical() " + belowViewExists);
        if(!belowViewExists) {
            final LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)
                    view.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
            layoutParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use `android:gravity`. This will align the children inside the container.

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not help. I think this is because I am using DataBinding.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect case for using [ConstraintView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html).
Its support for "missing" views is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_contact_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:text="@{info.getName()}"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />
```

hope this helps.